# A MKMapView delegate calling issue

Tags: ios5, ios6, mkmapview

I am facing an issue about MKMapView delegate.

In iOS5, When I clicked a Pin on the mapview, 
the`didSelectAnnotationView:` delegate will be called first, 
and the next is `viewForAnnotation:` delegate called.

In iOS6, When I clicked a Pin on the mapview,
the `viewForAnnotation:` will be called first, and the next is `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate called.

So my app works fine in iOS5, but works bad in iOS6,
it's because that there are coordinate informations that I need setting in the `didSelectAnnotationView:` delegate,

If `viewForAnnotation:` delegate are called before the `didSelectAnnotationView:`, then I'll get the wrong coordinate information.

Anybody got some idea? thank you!

Comment: well the error is on ios5 then ... how can it call `didSelectAnnotationView:` BEFORE it even gave the delegate a chance to provide a valid view (via viewForAnnotation)

Comment: Because before clicking the pin, the viewForAnnotaion delegate has already called, and added pin into the Mapview.

Comment: Using [annotation isKindOfClass:[MKMapAnnotation class]]
and [annotation isKindOfClass:[MKMapCalloutAnnotation class]]

Answer (score 1):

`viewForAnnotation` can and will be called when ever iOS needs to display one of your annotations. It is not related to when `didSelectAnnotationView` is called. You may think you found a pattern in iOS 5 but that was just a fluke of something in your app and should never have been relied on. If you use it correctly it will work in iOS 5 and 6 as well as 6.1, 6.2, 6.anything and I'd guess they won't change it much to iOS 7 either. If you look in the signature of `viewForAnnotation` you'll see that one of the parameters is an annotation. That is the item that your app is trying to draw and it has what ever information you gave the annotation when you called `[mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation]`. So cast it to your MKAnnotation implementation and extract the info.

Answer (score 0):

**modify the logic.**

Prepare the view in viewForAnnotation (which in theory -- can be called at any time anyway). It is the right place for this!

"The annotation view to display for the specified annotation or nil if you want to display a standard annotation view."